# What is the ionic conductivity of the hydroperoxide ion?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry, conductivity

Hydrogen peroxide is supposed to dissociate as

$$\ce{H2O2 <=> H+ + HO2-}$$

But I can't find a source for the conductivity, $\lambda$, of the  hydroperoxide anion $(\ce{OOH-}$ or $\ce{HO2-})$ on Google.

Comment: @HarikrishnanM If I'm reading that table right, 31% H2O2 solution has roughly $\Lambda_0 = 250$. But since the value of $\lambda_{H+}$ changes at 31% acc. to the paper, how do I get $\lambda_{HO2-}$ independently?

Comment: On reading closer, I think that table is only showing the acid's conductance after correcting for the H2O2-H2O, so I can't get my $\lambda$ anyway since they didn't record the total conductance including the solvent.

Comment: Well, I can't find $\lambda^0_{HO2^-}$. That's actually what I wanted.

Comment: Ohh I get it... will try and get something more as soon as possible.

Comment: By the way did you try the crc handbook of chemistry? It has all data there... the paper for your reference: https://cdnsciencepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1139/v58-108